# Consecutive independent means (not using sliding window) in R

Tags: r, moving-average

I'd like to calculate something similar to a rolling mean or moving average but without doing so via a sliding window. As an example, for the following set of numbers, I'd want the averages shown below the groups of 5:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1    
|    3    |   3.6   |   4.2   |   1.6   |  //mean of every 5 numbers
```

I know of the `movingAverages` available in the TTR lib, and the `rollmean` function which both use sliding windows, so it's reasonably straightforward to do something like this:

```
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1)
m <- rollmean(d,5)
m[seq(1,length(m),5)]
> [1] 3.0 3.6 4.2 1.6
```

But I've got a large dataset and there must be a more efficient way of calculating this... any ideas? I assume there's a function that will do exactly this but I can't think what this type of average is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1)

colMeans(matrix(x, nrow=5))
3.0 3.6 4.2 1.6
```

---

What this does:

- Convert your data to a matrix
- Take the column means

---

Since this is a single operation on a vector (a matrix is itself a vector), this should be blazingly fast.  For example, for a vector of 10 million elements:

```
x <- runif(1e7)
system.time(colMeans(matrix(x, nrow=5)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.02    0.07
```

Comment: I was just about to edit that, but you caught it first.  Nice solution.

Comment: Looks good, wouldn't have thought of that, cheers. What if, e.g. `length(x) %% 5 != 0` and I still wanted to mean of the last jagged col?

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here's how you can do it with `tapply`

```
tapply(x, rep(seq(length(x)/5),each=5), mean)
##   1   2   3   4 
## 3.0 3.6 4.2 1.6
```

This is easily adapted for a vector with a length not divisible by 5:

```
x <- c(x, 2)
tapply(x, head(rep(seq(ceiling(length(x)/5)), each=5),length(x)), mean)
##   1   2   3   4   5 
## 3.0 3.6 4.2 1.6 2.0
```